# How do I force floating boxes to have the same height?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look **[here](http://noxxar.com/demo/smarthomes/property/schelpwijk/)**.

Does anyone know how I can make sure that the white divs (class `col-sm-6`) that are floating next to each other always have the same height?

I can class them something like A and B if I could find a way using JavaScript or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not very helpful... Can you elaborate more we don't see any code and I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish? What div's are you talking about ?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far

Comment: Please add a code snippet, or better a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `min-height` CSS property for `.content-box`. Make sure the value is tall enough to cover the height of the tallest box.

Comment: I want the ones that are next to each other to be the exact same height though. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is to specify a fixed height for these.

```
.mh_x { height: 320px; }
```